# Pick up some first coordinate lists from list pool

Tags: python, list, coordinate

I have a string of coordinates of all nodes. Basically, I split the string into a pair of coordinates(x,y) (This is the result of part in the code: values = line.split() ). If I print "values", I will have the result as bellows:

```
['1', '3600', '2300']

['2', '3100', '3300']

['3', '4700', '5750']

['4', '5400', '5750']

['5', '5608', '7103']

['6', '4493', '7102']

['7', '3600', '6950']
```

I have 7 nodes with their coordinates. However I want to use the first 5 nodes to continue to append to coordinate list. How I can do it?

My code is:

```
def read_coordinates(self, inputfile):
    coord = []
    iFile = open(inputfile, "r")
    for i in range(6):  # skip first 6 lines
        iFile.readline()
    line = iFile.readline().strip()
    while line != "EOF":
        **values = line.split()**
        coord.append([float(values[1]), float(values[2])])
        line = iFile.readline().strip()
    iFile.close()
    return coord
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what you're meaning to say.
Can you please try to rephrase yourself?

Comment: I made it clear already :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code as follows:

```
def read_coordinates(self, inputfile):
    coord = []
    iFile = open(inputfile, "r")
    for i in range(6):  # skip first 6 lines
        iFile.readline()
    line = iFile.readline().strip()
    i = 0
    while i < 5 
        values = line.split()
        coord.append([float(values[1]), float(values[2])])
        line = iFile.readline().strip()
        i += 1
    iFile.close()
    return coord
```

Now you while loop will only run for first 5 lines which will give you results for first 5 nodes

Comment: What if I want to read from node 4 to node. However I don't want to delete "line != "EOF" " code. Cause at the end of string, there is the string named "EOF".

Comment: you can use the keyword `continue` :
keep the while loop as follows : `while line != "EOF":`
and add an if statement `if (i <5 ): i +=1; continue`... can you please upvote my answer if you have privileges ... hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will do the trick, with the added bonus of using a context manager to keep the function tidier.

```py
def read_coordinates(self, inputfile):

    coord = []
    with open(inputfile, "r") as iFile:
        for i in xrange(6):  # Skip first 6 lines
            next(iFile)

        for i in xrange(5):  # Read the next 5 lines
            line = iFile.readline().strip()
            values = line.split()
            coord.append([float(values[1]), float(values[2])])
    return coord
```